# Find Multiple Substring from a String Using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a column **log**. I need to extract values from that log column and make **4 new columns**

My table:
[image]

Output I need:

[image]

Comment: What is the logic here? Why `James Jonson` but not `Super admin`, for example?

Comment: Which dbms are you using. (The answer will probably take advantage if product specific string functions.)

Comment: Show us some more _different_ possible log column data, and the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh SQL Server

Comment: @HoneyBadger  pls check the edited question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string really always follows *exactly* that format, you can use something funky like this:

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(1000)
    = N'Super admin James Johnson<jamesjohnson@gmail.com> updated profile of admin Sam Welson<samwelson@gmail.com>';

SELECT *
,      PARSENAME(repl.val, 4) AS AdminName
,      PARSENAME(repl.val, 3) AS AdminEmail
,      PARSENAME(repl.val, 2) AS UpdateName
,      PARSENAME(repl.val, 1) AS UpdateEmail
FROM (
         VALUES (@test)
     ) AS X (T)
OUTER APPLY (
                VALUES (REPLACE(
                                   REPLACE(
                                              REPLACE(
                                                         REPLACE(X.T, 'Super admin ', '') --Remove this completely
                                                     ,   ' updated profile of admin ' --Replace this with a .
                                                     ,   '.'
                                                     )
                                          ,   '<'   --Replace this with a . and [ (so the . in the email isn't parsed)
                                          ,   '.['
                                          )
                               ,   '>' --Reaplace with ] to complemanted the previous ]
                               ,   ']'
                               )
                       )
            ) AS repl (val);
```

Which gives:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+------------------------+------------+---------------------+
|                                                     T                                                      |                                   val                                   |   AdminName   |       AdminEmail       | UpdateName |     UpdateEmail     |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+------------------------+------------+---------------------+
| Super admin James Johnson<jamesjohnson@gmail.com> updated profile of admin Sam Welson<samwelson@gmail.com> | James Johnson.[jamesjohnson@gmail.com].Sam Welson.[samwelson@gmail.com] | James Johnson | jamesjohnson@gmail.com | Sam Welson | samwelson@gmail.com |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+------------------------+------------+---------------------+
```

This abuses the [PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function, which is meant to parse 4 part named objects (server_name.database_name.schema_name.object_name).

Comment: Thanks your query work. I am going to use your logic and add some of my own.